# In - app billing issue

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-play-services

I have downloaded sample project of v3 In-app billing from developer and followed all the procedures like they have said. But its giving a message saying "The item you requested is not available for purchase."

As per advice given in other links I also published my sample app to play store, I downloaded the app from playstore, but still getting same error.

[image]

Comment: did you register the item at the play store? You really have to give more details.

Comment: you cannot buy your own items, try with some other id

Comment: @Budius: what did you mean by register the item @ playstore?

Comment: @SyedZahidAli - Yeah. I tried that I registered in account details of Developer console in License Testing.

Comment: still having the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. As said, you can't buy your own items, but you can use a test email address. One of the Play Store menu setting is to pick the email address to use.
2. Despite Google saying it takes 2-3 hours to propagate changes, it can take several days in the worst circumstances.